# LM350 not reducing the ripple

Tags: power-supply, linear-regulator, ripple

I share the picture of the schematic of my circuit.

I want to use the LM350 variable voltage regulator to reduce the 40mV p-p ripple i have in my bridge rectified DC.

Though it has no effect at all. 
Why could this be?

My load draws current and i can adjust the voltage output of LM350. I couldn't make it to reduce the ripple.

Would you point me to the right direction?

Thank you.

**In the below schematic there are some wrong values.
The output voltage is 8.39 V and load draws 750mA.**

The ripple frequency is around 250Hz.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: What is the ripple frequency?

Comment: And why didn't you include the output capacitor called for in the LM350 datasheet?

Comment: it is around 250hz

Comment: Well i did but then trying to spot the problem i simplified the circuit as much as possible, the output cap doesn't change anything, at least when it is 1uF.

Comment: Is the output voltage 4.5 V or 9.5 V?

Comment: There's an embedded schematic editor you can use. This should prevent having to explain all the things that you did draw in the schematic but are unreadable or ambiguous.

Comment: 4.5V sorry for the bad quality photo.

Comment: OK, something else is wrong then. Your resistor values should be giving 7.5 V.

Comment: I am really sorry i measured again and it gives 8.39 V which is close to 7.5 probably my load is a little bit different than 600mA but it looks ok. I remembered an old value and wrote it there in the schematic sorry. I measured the load with Amp Meter it is 750mA. I will edit the question.

Comment: What is the ripple at the input side to the regulator on the 11.5V DC?  Also, many regulator circuits of this type include a cap from the ADJ input to GND (~10uf) in order to improve transient response.

Comment: Did you measure the voltage at the LM350 input with the load attached?

Comment: What is your load ? stepped or continuous? , resistive or reactive? if reactive ? what is ESR? or DCR?  What is Vout vs Iout DC?

Comment: My load is continuous, resistive, vOut is 8.39 V when current draw is 750mA.

Comment: Are you within dropout limits? Where is your output cap?

Answer (score 6):

Notice in the TI datasheet, line regulation is spec'ed with \$V_{in}-V_{out}\ge 3\ {\rm V}\$. With 11.5 V at input and 8.4 V at output, you just barely meet that requirement.

Possibly the input voltage at the LM350 is actually a bit lower than 11.5 V due to wire losses, or because your unregulated rectifier output has dropped under load.  Anyway, what you told us about output voltage was off by 4 V, so I don't hardly trust what you've told us about input voltage. If that's the case, you are operating in drop-out.

In drop-out, line regulation is practically non-existent, and any ripple on the input will transfer 1-to-1 to the output.

If this is the issue, when you reduce the output voltage (by changing the adjustment resistor values), the line regulation should improve dramatically.

Comment: I think you might be right. I am checking immediately and give feedback.

Comment: Yes you are right. After the load my input voltage becomes 9.5 V then there is only 1V difference between in and out. I will drop it to 6V and try thank you very much.

Comment: The Photon, how would i then keep that 3V and more distance between input and output? When i lower the output also input comes down. For example Out 6.2 Input becomes 7.5 again around 1V difference.

Comment: 1. Make sure the (transformer and) rectifier is able to supply sufficient current for your load at 11.5 V (or 10 V or whatever). 2. Don't program the output of the LM350 to be above that voltage minus 3 V.

Comment: Could it be because of cables? They are standard crocodiles. Transformer can supply 1.5 Amps with ease so its not that and rectifier diodes are 3 Amp rated. They don't heat at all. I am changing the value of R(Adj) i tried to lower it until 4.7ohms the output voltage drops but input voltage follows keeping the 1v difference between each other.

Comment: It shouldn't be the wires, even AWG 28 shouldn't have more than some mV drop with less than 1 A load. Can you just put a resistive load on the output of the transformer to be sure it's not the cause?

Comment: @AliSomay - I don't understand some of your story. However I can help regarding your question: "*Could it be because of cables? They are standard crocodiles.*" Measuring low-ish resistances can be tricky (measure shorted test lead resistance first) - remember power-**off** for this test. Also measure the voltage drop across each cable when **under load** (this may be more accurate and revealing, as it is in the "under load" condition). Some of the pre-made "cables with fitted crocodile clips" are very poor - thin copper in the wires, crocodiles badly crimped (not soldered) to the wires etc.

Answer (score 1):

Added

### Problem:

Too much dropout for a high current LDO ( L is not low enough)   Measurements and specs are unclear.

### Solution:

**Use a 1 ohm power PFET with heat sink. ( or a 100 mOhm PFET and  switch  it at 50kHz with 10uH choke with LC filter)  OpAmp may be reversed and use NFET.**

Dear Ali: You ought to say you want vacuum tube heater current at 6V with 1mV ripple with 300mA/tube or -75 dB in the first place. Is this for 2 tubes ? I would have created 13.5 or 13 V DC then used series heaters with 150mA/tube with a CC regulator that has > -80 dB line regulation error.  Half the current also improves line regulation ripple by 6dB.  Why 350Hz and why not 35kHz?  Then you dont need 30mF caps.

> A better design may be to supply CC so that there is no 5x cold surge and 80dB loop gain at 350Hz or 3.5MHz GBW.

### **Design specs.**

- -80 db min line regulation error @ 350Hz
- 1A max  CC mode set by user for 4W load (tungsten @ 6V)
- R sense set for < 1/4W R.
- High GBW and Ron ~1 Ohm  ~5W dissipation .

[image]

You shall not use a 10mOhm FET because the feedthru capacitance is too high.

### Test Results

tinyurl.com/yalvlj6b  (Falstad sim)

- using 1Vp square ripple input instead of 20mV  ( to make it easier to measure low ripple out)
- assumed 4W tungsten load at 6V
- set CC to 0.11V/ 0.15 Ohm
- with 0.1mA ripple out  = -77dB from DC at 1V ripple input  improved by 20 dB at 100mV input ripple.
- Series pass FET dissipates as much as load near half voltage.
- result: OK  given mismatched supply source.

---

You need to understand the datasheet.

There is a complex Zout(f) and you have a complex load ZL(f). The ratio approximates the step load regulation error.  <s>Since you have 100 Hz input ripple yet 350Hz output ripple, I presume your ripple is all load regulation error and not Vdrop related.</s>

There must be a preload to reduce load regulation error and compensation at the Vadj and Vout to support a declining Zout(f) and Zadj( feedback).

Without going over the datasheet examples in detail , I expect you to do this and see examples of 10mF on output with low ESR and and understand that 1% load regulation error on 10V means 100mV ripple.  This can be reduced by above compensation caps, but I will not do all the work for you.

Do you know Bode plots and impedance ratios?

Can you define your transient load properly?

Can you supply a tabe of step load current and f with ripple values with added trace photos so we can see spectral ripple?

### Most important

Why do you need low ripple and what is your spec or acceptance criteria?

Comment: I will check the Bode plots and impedance ratios and the datasheet again but only one thing to correct i have the output and input ripple the same frequency and they are both around 250Hz.

Comment: I am heating the 12ax7 vacuum tubes with this supply. I want extremely low ripple 1mv p-p or less to prevent cross talk between the heater and the cathode and also other parts of the audio signal amplification stage.

Comment: Step size of the load current? I can do it by simulating the load with different resistors or do you need a spice simulation?

Comment: By transient load, do you mean the inrush current when i power the system or , are there transients in my load. The current draw looked pretty much constant in the amp meter. Sorry for my ignorrance and thank you for the help :) Also do we wonder the ratio between Zout(f) and Zadj?

Comment: Sorry I thought one scribble said 20ms

Comment: See my design http://tinyurl.com/yalvlj6b  1Vp square ripple input @ constant current with 0.1mA / 700mA ripple out